# HTML5 vs Android or iOS

Tags: android, ios, html

Without considering games, what are the current real benefits of programming with the native APIs for Android and iOS instead of HTML5 ? People keep saying HTML5 is a great promise, isn't it already a valid option ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason HTML5 is not yet a valid option is simple.  It's only on Working Draft status with the W3C.  In other words, it's still subject to change and therefore should not be used in anything that requires any kind of stability of the standard.

As for the benefits, there are more benefits than simply "HTML5 isn't ready yet".  For example:

- Programming in the native APIs offers a significant speed advantage at runtime.
- Applications programmed in the native APIs offer access to a wider range of current and future peripheral devices.
- Applications programmed in the native APIs do not require a web server to run.
- The native APIs are significantly more extensive (in terms of features) than HTML5.
- Native applications offer security and privacy advantages to users for certain specific applications (eg, contact details of friends/family).
- Not sure if I should list this, being an open source advocate, but HTML5 applications by nature reveal (at least part of) their source to the user.  In some situations, some people may feel this is a disadvantage.
- You can sell native apps on the marketplace.  Monetizing HTML5 apps is more difficult and can lead to intrusive monetization methods (such as advertisement).

There are a few disadvantages too, but since the question only really asks about benefits, I believe it is beyond the scope of my answer to list them.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to go HTML is cross-platform support and hence faster time-to-market. There are a few reasons why you might not go with embedded browsers (HTML):

1. Features. If you need 2d/3d drawing, audio, notifications, sockets, locations, network info, etc.. then you need native access. You can access those from HTML5 via a wrapper, but this somehow defeats the HTML5 promise - cross platform developments.
2. Embedded browsers are (sometimes visibly) slower.
3. No real HTML5 support: HTML5 is not yet fully supported on browsers on devices.
4. Native look and feel. This can be simulated via HTML, but will never perform the same.

Given all this, HTML is viable only if you have a concrete project (known customer) and need to do it quickly on a limited budget and there are requirements to support multiple platforms.

OTOH, if you plan to target the app markets, then keep in mind that there is already A LOT of apps out there and that competition is fierce. People lean towards apps that are really polished and, IMHO, you'd have hard time creating one via HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the HTML5 isn't due to really be a standard for almost a decade argument, I think the biggest advantage of native apps is disconnected functionality. HTML5 does include API's that should allow this functionality, but to my knowledge no one really supports it yet. The user may be willing to wait through a slow data connection download once, but EVERY time your app runs? Probably not.